# Scrapy: Ways to put all posts in a thread TOGETHER?

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and here is a problem I ran into recently. My object is to crawl threads in a forum which includes all posts in each thread. Here is the code, it's quite rough :)

```
class forumSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'forumSpider'
    allow_domain = ['letsebuy.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.letsebuy.com/forum-26-1.html',]

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('thread-\d*-\d-\d')),callback = 'parse_thread'),
    ]

    def parse_thread(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        thread = ThreadItem()
        thread['title'] = sel.xpath('//span[@id = "thread_subject"]/text()').extract()
        thread['url'] = response.url
        thread['posts'] = list()
        thread['posts'].extend(self.get_posts(response))
        #next_pages = sel.xpath('//div[@class = "pgs mtm mbm cl"]/div[@class = "pg"]/a[re:test(text(),"\d+")]/@href').extract()
        return thread

    # Parse all posts in a thread page
    def get_posts(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        posts = sel.xpath('//div[re:test(@id, "post_\d+")]')

        for r in posts:
            post = PostItem()
            post['author'] = r.xpath('.//div[@class = "authi"]//a[1]//text()').extract()
            post['content'] = str().join(r.xpath('.//td[re:test(@id, "postmessage_\d+$")]/text()').extract())
            yield post
```

The code works well for one thread page. However, some threads with lots of posts contains several pages. I can collect all posts' url of a certain thread. Is there a way I can `request` all these pages, parse them using `get_posts` and fill all the `postItem` into `thread['posts']`.

Hope someone can help me out! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new requests in `parse_thread` function and pass the thread item using meta:

```
 def parse_thread(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    thread = ThreadItem()
    thread['title'] = sel.xpath('//span[@id = "thread_subject"]/text()').extract()
    thread['url'] = response.url
    thread['posts'] = list()
    thread['posts'].extend(self.get_posts(response))
    next_pages = sel.xpath('//div[@class = "pgs mtm mbm cl"]/div[@class = "pg"]/a[re:test(text(),"\d+")]/@href').extract()
    if next_pages:
        url = next_pages.pop()
        yield Request(url, meta={'thread':thread, 'next_pages' : next_pages}, callback=self.get_more_posts)
    else:
        yield thread

 def get_more_posts(self, response):
    thread = response.meta['thread']
    thread['posts'].extend(self.get_posts(response))
    next_pages = item['next_pages']
    if next_pages:
        url = next_pages.pop()
        yield Request(url, meta={'thread' : thread, 'next_pages' : next_pages}, callback=self.get_more_posts)
    else:
        yield thread
```

Cleaner solution is to store thread id in each `PostItem`. As an example for [this thread](http://www.letsebuy.com/thread-1419553-1-1.html) you store in `thread['id'] = 1419553` and for all corresponding posts you have `post['thread_id'] = 1419553`. Now whenever you see the first page of the thread you call `parse_thread`. For consequent pages you call `get_posts`. The code would look like this:

```
class forumSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'forumSpider'
    allow_domain = ['letsebuy.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.letsebuy.com/forum-26-1.html',]

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('thread-\d+-1-\d')),callback = 'parse_thread'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('thread-\d+-([2-9]|\d\d+)-\d')),callback = 'get_posts'),
    ]

    def parse_thread(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        thread = ThreadItem()
        yield self.get_posts(response)
        thread['title'] = sel.xpath('//span[@id = "thread_subject"]/text()').extract()
        thread['url'] = response.url
        thread['id'] = re.search(r'thread-(\d+)', response.url).group(1)
        yield thread

    # Parse all posts in a thread page
    def get_posts(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        posts = sel.xpath('//div[re:test(@id, "post_\d+")]')
        thread_id = re.search(r'thread-(\d+)', response.url).group(1)
        for r in posts:
            post = PostItem()
            post['thread_id'] = thread_id
            post['author'] = r.xpath('.//div[@class = "authi"]//a[1]//text()').extract()
            post['content'] = str().join(r.xpath('.//td[re:test(@id, "postmessage_\d+$")]/text()').extract())
            yield post
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply and it works!
I'm interested in how you will implement to meet such requirement.
Maybe I'm doing it using not the most suitable features of scrapy for my target, so there is lots of duplicated code.
If time permits, I'd like to know your opinion.

Comment: @Tremendo, I have updated the answer with slightly cleaner solution.